# Viewing user accounts

Tags: users

I have the following items configured in:
Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings

[image]

The problem I have is that I want to display user email and timezone.  On the "Manage Display" these fields are not shown so I cannot configure them.  Note that I am using the "Email Registration" module to allow users to register with email and essentially hide their user_id.   Here is the display page.

[image]

Note: when I display email it shows like this instead of showing the actual email which does exist:
[image]